# Getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query for all JPA retrival queries like findbyId(), findAll()

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi when I am trying to retrieve the entity data using JPA predefined and custom methods method queries getting this error :

: Unauthorized error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.

For example if I call this getUserEntityByUserEmailId() method from the dao class it gives No results were returned by the query in logs and for findAll() method also gives the same.

but I am able to save data by using the save() method Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

here is the Dao class

```
@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    @Override
    public UserEntity createUser(UserDto userDto) {
        UserEntity userEntity=modelMapper.map(userDto,UserEntity.class);
        userEntity.setUserRole(Set.of(UserRole.END_USER));
        userEntity.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        return userRepository.save(userEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserExistsByEmailOrMobileNumber(String userEmail, String mobileNumber) {
        return userRepository.existsByUserEmailOrUserMobileNumber(userEmail,mobileNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserEntity> getUserEntityByUserEmailId(String username) {
        return userRepository.findUserEntityByUserEmail(username);
    }   

}
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    boolean existsByUserEmailOrUserMobileNumber(String userEmail, String userMobileNumber);

    Optional<UserEntity> findUserEntityByUserEmail( String userEmail);
}
```

Entity class

```
@Entity(name = "user_model")
@Data
@Setter
@Getter
public class UserEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Gender gender;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String userEmail;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String userMobileNumber;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    private Date birthDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<UserRole> userRole;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

In the console log quires are generated and those working as expected

select u1_0.id,u1_0.birth_date,u1_0.created_at,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.gender,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.updated_at,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_mobile_number,u1_0.user_role from user_model u1_0 where u1_0.user_email=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.birth_date,u1_0.created_at,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.gender,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.updated_at,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_mobile_number,u1_0.user_role from user_model u1_0 where u1_0.user_email=?

Comment: finally, I resolved it. this issue because of set<Role> field in userEntity. I have to create on join table between userEntity and role table. So that whenever we are feching a user entity, JPA can automatically add roles. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I resolved it. this issue because of **set** field in **userEntity**. I have to create on join table between userEntity and role table. So that whenever we are fetching a user entity, JPA can automatically add roles. Thank you